# Why am I getting geckodriver.log error even if I have pasted geckodriver in right place?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver, bots

Someone please tell if my code has any flaw.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium import webdriver


class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()

def login(self):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.get('https://twitter.com/login')
    time.sleep(12)
    email = bot.find_element_by_class_name('emil-input')
    password = bot.find_element_by_name('session[password]')
    email.clear()
    password.clear()
    email.send_keys(self.username)
    password.send_keys(self.password)
    password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)
def like_tweet(self,hashtag):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.get('https://twitter.com/search?q='+hashtag+'&src=typd')
    time.sleep(3)

ed = TwitterBot('john@yahoo.com','blablabla')
ed.login()
ed.like_tweet('john')
```

---

This is the error which I get while I run my code. How do I fix this?
I will be very greatful. Please help a newbie of python....

```
 log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver.log'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to specify the Geckodriver executable:

```
self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\pathtogeckodriver\geckodriver.exe')
```

Edit: Of course take into account that slashes depend on OS